# Can I use Engineering codes like ASHRAE , NFPA and UPC in my software without permission?

Tags: software

Say, I want to use the UPC code Water Supply Fixture Unit tables in my software that I'm writing ... is it okay or there will be copyright issues?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something between legal issues and personal opinions

Answer (score 2):

This is a question specific to the software you want to use. You will need to read up on their license description or ask the person/company who wrote the software.

You will not be able to get a good answer from this forum. In particular, you will not be able to get anything that you can rely on from a legal point of view.